# Is it possible to declare an anonymous instance in an union in C++?

Tags: c++, stm32, low-level, bare-metal

While working with *low-level* C++ for bare-metal embedded systems (STM32), I came across a use case for an "anonymous union member" declaration with non trivial (a struct) type. Is such a thing possible ?

I have tried the following kind of code :

```cpp
struct Specialization_CR1_t
{
        uint32_t a :1 ;
        uint32_t   :31;
};

struct CR1_t
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t  : 1;
            uint32_t b: 1;
            uint32_t  :30;
        } ;
        // Few tries...
        // Specialization_CR1_t {};
        // Specialization_CR1_t;
        Specialization_CR1_t () ; 
        // Fails with "expected unqualified-id before ')'"
    };
};

int main()
{
    //The goal :
    struct CR1_t CR1;
    CR1.a = 1;
    CR1.b = 0;
}
```

The goal is to avoid having `CR1.<thing>.a`. Obviously, there is the possibility to directly declare `Specialization_CR1_t` anonymously in the `union`, however the ultimate goal is to be able to use a template and `tmpl_CR1_t` instead of "just" `Specialization_CR1_t`.

I am aware of the potential memory issues with the stuff displayed here. However, since this is in bare-metal embedded environment, the memory structure is fully known, the bits are packed well and tight and the tool-chain is fixed (no issues with bitfields).

Moreover, since this structure will be directly mapped in memory, I cannot afford the overhead of another variable. The total size of my structure have to be 32 bits and writing into `a` or `b` have to change only the correct bit.

Best regards !

Comment: An anonymous struct is not allowed in standard C++.   Even without using `Specialization_CR1_t` as a member, your code is invalid.   Unfortunately, some C++ compilers support that by default as an extension (maybe since since C does(?))  - if you crank up your compiler to issue more warnings/diagnostics (e.g. `-Wall -pedantic` for `gcc`) it will probably tell you that.   Naming members of a struct or union does not give more "overhead" in terms of memory usage anyway.

Comment: Actually it is not forbidden either as stated in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes : "The name may be omitted, in which case the class is unnamed (note that unnamed class cannot be final)"
Moreover, the issue about named members is not related to the overhead, but to my goal.

Comment: You missed my point.  The name `Foo` in `struct Foo { <members>};` within a class/union can be omitted.    The name `Instance` in `struct {<members>} Instance` cannot.

Comment: Oh, ok. I actually read about that. However since C11 (which introduce this), it seems that most C++ compilers accept it even though it is not standard. I used it thoroughly without issue since few years without issue. The point is to use that within a union. (It might work within a class, but that would be surprising).
In this context, however, it is really useful...

Comment: Yeah, okay.   In addition to specifying your chipset, you may also want to identify your compiler.   If you're willing to use non-standard language features, you're going to be in the realm of using features specific to your compiler.   And more than one compiler is available to build for ARM-based chipsets.

Comment: should never use unions and structs across compile domains nor use unions like this that is not their purpose, same code can be generated with something much cleaner and more reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISO C11 allows anonymous structs inside other struct/unions.  This is supported as an extension by some C++ compilers, including GNU-compatible (g++, clang++), and by MSVC++.  [The GCC manual has some examples](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html).

This is AFAIK not allowed in ISO C++.  If you're using a compiler that doesn't implement this extension, see the middle part of this answer.

---

I'm pretty sure the anonymous union is a red herring here, and you'd have exactly the same problem trying to declare `b` as a 32-bit object with 31 bits of padding and 1 value-bit using that anonymous-struct in any other context.

If it was legal inside an anonymous union, it would be legal anywhere.  (But instead it's not, and is legal nowhere in ISO C.  As @Peter points out in comments, the name `Instance` in `struct {<members>} Instance` can't be omitted.  And if you make it `struct foo {<members>};` you'd just be declaring a type, not an instance.)

You'll probably just have to write a class with `operator=` and `operator bool` overloads, which you can do because this is C++.

(Consider retitling the question with what you're actually trying to do: write an anonymous struct with a bitfield member.)

Or if you want help with the wrapper class, take a step back from the X-Y problem where the anonymous-struct approach has apparently hit a dead end (unless there is some compiler-specific support for it) and ask a new question about writing a convenient wrapper that exposes a single bit in a word as an integer type.  With vendor headers, compiler extensions, or plain or C++ operator overloads.

Although given how you're using the union, you can do this to get what you want, at least without templates, right?

```
struct CR1bits
{
    uint32_t a: 1;
    uint32_t b: 1;
    uint32_t  :30;
};
```

So maybe you should be asking something about how you can template this to what, have different type names that have some subset of the named bits?  Maybe the C preprocessor can help with that, in a more clunky way that still lets the code using these types look the way you want.

---

## Anonymous structs are C11 standard, or a C++ extension:

GNU C++, and MSVC, both support anonymous structs.  This compiles and works:

```
union Obj {
   struct {       // extension: anonymous struct
      int x;
      int y;
      int z;
   };
   int elems[3];
};
```

`a->x` or `a->elems[0]` both access the same object (assuming standard struct layout with no padding).

And apparently this is standard ISO C11.

Comment: So this is a well argumented "No". It seems quite legit that it is not possible though.
I finally decided to go one level up (to add `a` and `b` into the `Specialization_CR1_t` ) and play around with ifdefs. This can works only because my source files are generated through a script and I'm quite restrictive one my defines. Definitely not a good way to work in a more "normal" use case.
Thanks for your constructive remarks.

Comment: @JFaucher: Turns out some compilers do support anonymous structs.  I recently wanted to turn a struct into a union with an array so I could index the members, and to my surprise it compiled.  Turns out GCC implements that as a C++ extension, and it's standard in ISO C11.

Comment: Just to add some information, at least GCC implement it in standard C++ (as in, you don't need to use a `gnu++XX` version for it to work.
I used that quite extensively without *seeing* any issue (with GCC in `c++11` and higher)
If you want to checkout the project i'm working on (early dev stage, actually working now but I saw that the relevant commits have not been pushed), you can check [SooL github repository](https://github.com/SooL/core/tree/svd)